# How opengl differentiates between software and hardware implementations?

Tags: opengl

If i have a software implementation and if also have a graphic card which supports opengl , then which of these is used by the opengl?

Answer (score 2):

This is both a simple and a complicated question. The simple answer is that OpenGL neither knows nor cares. OpenGL is not a *thing*; it is a document. A specification. Implementations of OpenGL are things.

Which brings up the complicated part. How you talk to an OpenGL implementation depends on what platform you live on. MesaGL can be compiled as nothing more than a library you link to.

If you want hardware acceleration, then you now have to deal with the OS, because the OS owns the GPU. Mesa as a driver is implemented through the glX system. It hooks into X-windows and X-windows' OpenGL context creation functions can give you a context that is implemented by software Mesa drivers. Or by hardware Mesa drivers. If you're using other drivers, then they too hook into X-windows. These are all tied into X-windows "displays".

On Windows, it's much simpler. There is precisely one ICD driver. If it's installed, and you use a pixel format that it supports (aka: something reasonable), then you get hardware accelerated OpenGL through it. If it isn't you get Microsoft's software implementation.